# django makemessages issue

Tags: python, django, translation

I am running python 2.7 and django 1.8.11 on Windows 7.

After adding in the necessary translation string literals, I am trying to translate my site. I have followed the instructions as per the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/#message-files). This includes [installing the GNU gettext utilities for windows 7](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/#gettext-on-windows) and the necessary locale folders/directories in the correct language code.

In the virtual environment & at the command prompt of the root directory of my project, I run:

```
django-admin makemessages -l de
```

I get the following error at the command prompt:

```
CommandError: Unable to find a locale path to store translations for file fabfile.py
```

In the root directory of my project, I have the following files, which is where the `fabfile.py` is located:

[image]

I have tried (temporarily) removing the `fabfile.py` from the directory. When I tried this, the error message I received when running `django-admin makemessages -l de` is:

```
CommandError: Unable to find a locale path to store translations for file manage.py
```

It appears that the `makemessages` command is including all the `.py` and `.txt` files in the root directory. I am not sure if this is the correct procedure or not.

**How do I not include the .py & .txt files in the root directory of my project when I run the `makemessages` command?**

Comment: What third packages/apps do you have installed? Have you searched for the fabfile.py file within the virtualenv source folders?

Comment: Have you created a locale directory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure how or why, but when I tried this yesterday, it did not work, but now does work. Very frustrating.

I had to run the `makemessages` command **one extra directory inside my project root directory.**

I hope this helps someone out there.

Comment: Running `python ../manage.py makemessages` inside `project_dir/locale` does indeed work.

Answer (score 1):

You must mkdir locale at folder of fabfile.py and manage.py.