# django makemessages - CommandError: errors happened while running msguniq - syntax error

Tags: python, django, translation

I'm using django 1.10.5 with python 3.6.5 on a Windows 7 OS.

I have a test app that has existing translation strings.

The `makemessages` command worked in the past.

However, in the last week I have received the following error when I've attempted to run the `django-admin makemessages` command:

```
(myappenv36) C:\Users\me\desktop\myapp\myapp [master ≡ +0 ~13 -0 !]> dja
ngo-admin makemessages
CommandError: errors happened while running msguniq
C:\Users\me\desktop\myapp\myapp\locale\django.pot:1783:3: syntax error
C:\Users\me\desktop\myapp\myapp\locale\django.pot:1783: keyword "core" un
known
C:\Users\me\desktop\myapp\myapp\locale\django.pot:1783: keyword "models"
unknown
C:\Users\me\desktop\myapp\myapp\locale\django.pot:1783: keyword "py" unkn
own
C:\Users\me\desktop\myapp\myapp\locale\django.pot:1783: keyword "core" un
known
C:\Users\me\desktop\myapp\myapp\locale\django.pot:1783: keyword "models"
unknown
C:\Users\me\desktop\myapp\myapp\locale\django.pot:1783: keyword "py" unkn
own
C:\Users\me\desktop\myapp\myapp\locale\django.pot:1785: keyword "core" un
known
C:\Users\me\desktop\myapp\myapp\locale\django.pot:1785: keyword "models"
unknown
C:\Users\me\desktop\myapp\myapp\locale\django.pot:1785: keyword "py" unkn
own
C:\Users\me\desktop\myapp\myapp\locale\django.pot:4543:3: syntax error
C:\Users\me\desktop\myapp\myapp\locale\django.pot:4543: keyword "template
s" unknown
C:\Users\me\desktop\myapp\myapp\locale\django.pot:4543: keyword "base" un
known
C:\Users\me\desktop\myapp\myapp\locale\django.pot:4543: keyword "resume_m
enu" unknown
C:\Users\me\desktop\myapp\myapp\locale\django.pot:4543: keyword "html" un
known
C:\Users\me\desktop\myapp\myapp\locale\django.pot:4545: keyword "template
s" unknown
C:\Users\me\desktop\myapp\myapp\locale\django.pot:4545: keyword "header"
unknown
C:\Users\me\desktop\myapp\myapp\locale\django.pot:4545: keyword "header"
unknown
C:\Users\me\desktop\myapp\myapp\locale\django.pot:4545: keyword "html" un
known
C:\Users\me\desktop\myapp\myapp\locale\django.pot:4548: keyword "template
s" unknown
msguniq: too many errors, aborting
```

I have thoroughly searched Google and SO for an answer to this issue, but I have come up blank.

These are the attempts I have made to fix the issue:

**1.** Followed the [django 1.10 docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/translation/#gettext-on-windows) and re-installed the gettext from this [download](https://mlocati.github.io/articles/gettext-iconv-windows.html).

**2.** Moved all my .po & .mo files from my locale directory and tried running the `django-admin makemessages` on empty translation files. This gives me the same error message.

**Can anyone give me an insight to the error message and how to fix this issue?**

Thanks.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this error? I have the same error and I don't know how to fix it

Comment: Jacek B Budzynski - I cannot correctly remember my solution. However, this post may be a solution for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37559647/django-makemessages-issue/37636182#37636182

Comment: Thank you! Finally, I have modified the conflicting texts and deleted the characters with accents (Fecha creación > Fecha creacion) and works.. For some reason in this file the accents fail, although in the rest of the project they work correctly

Comment: @Jacek B Budzynski - now that you mention this issue, I now recall that the accents do cause issues with the compiling of the translation files (I was translating from the English language to the French language). Only when I completed a find and replace with an acceptable accent did the issue resolve.

Answer (score 0):

For me there was a missing `#` in front of this line in my `django.po` file:

```
: .\my_project\templates\base.html:114
```

after doing:

```
$ django-admin makemessages --locale 'de_DE' --ignore=venv/*
```

*Wrong code:*

```
#: .\my_project\templates\account\signup.html:9
#: .\my_project\templates\account\signup.html:19
: .\my_project\templates\base.html:114
msgid "Sign Up"
msgstr "Registrieren"
```

**Good code:**

```
#: .\my_project\templates\account\signup.html:9
#: .\my_project\templates\account\signup.html:19
: .\my_project\templates\base.html:114
msgid "Sign Up"
msgstr "Registrieren"
```